# Onde fica armazenado o caminho das imagens de posts no Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou montando um plugin no cakephp personalizado, pois o plugin do próprio wordpress não funciona, até então, consegui utilizar tudo, da table de posts do wordpress, o problema é que não sei onde que fica o caminho das imagens dos posts.
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os arquivos ficam em `wp-content/uploads/`

No banco de dados:

As **imagens destacadas** ficam salvas na tabela `postmeta` com o `meta_key` de `_wp_attached_file` e relacionadas com a `meta_key` de `_thumbnail_id`

As **imagens de dentro do post** tem o nome salvo na própria tabela `posts` junto com o conteúdo em `post_content`

Um exemplo de query para listar os posts com a imagem destacada é:

```
select *, (select p.guid from wp_postmeta pm, wp_posts p where pm.meta_key="_thumbnail_id" and pm.post_id=post.id and p.ID=pm.meta_value) as imagem_destacada from wp_posts post where post_status='publish' and post_type="post";
```

Comment: certo, mas onde que eu pego o nome das imagens?

Comment: @MichelHenriq da uma olhada na resposta editada

Comment: fiz uma pesquisa na unha passando o id do post, mas ele não trouxe o nome da imagem, existe uma função que trabalha em cima do meta_key?

Comment: Dentro do wordpress pode-se usar `<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' );
echo $thumb['0']; ?>`

Comment: Aí que está o problema, eu estou desenvolvendo um plugin personalizado dentro do cakephp, e não dá pra usar as funções do wp no cakephp, por isso estou fazer o recursivo de tudo para ver como funciona, porque preciso montar essas imagens na mão.

Comment: você tendo o id do post é só dar um select na tabela `postmeta` com o `post_id` do seu post e o `meta_key` com  `_wp_attached_file`, ele vai retornar algo como `2015/11/img.jpg` ai é só adicionar o `wp-content/uploads/` antes e já era

Comment: não entendi onde entra esse `_wp_attached_file`.
Ele é uma função do wordpress?

Comment: `select * from postmeta where post_id = 168 and meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"`

Comment: rodei essa consulta no meu banco de dados e retornou zero

Comment: Certifique-se de verificar se a tabela postmeta não tem prefixos ex `wp_postmeta`, e coloque o id de um post que contenha a imagem destacada (thumbnail)

Comment: `_wp_attached_file` é imagem e `_wp_attachment_metadata` é o conteúdo do post?

Comment: `_wp_attached_file` é o nome do arquivo com endereço a partir do `wp-content/uploads/` e o `_wp_attachment_metadata` como a propria terminação em `meta` sugere são informações sobre esta imagem, ex: largura, altura, mime type entre vários outros.

Comment: entendi, então no caso, se eu quero pegar os ultimos 3 posts inseridos que tenham imagem é só fazer um join passando os críterios..

Comment: Como posso diferenciar posts de uploads de imagens?

Comment: Exato isso mesmo, na tabela de posts você filtra os itens que quer pelo `post_type`, `post_status`, etc... mas isso já merece uma nova pergunta para não fugir do escopo da pergunta atual.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31713/discussion-between-michel-henriq-and-alanrezende).

Comment: e como dou um echo nessa query?